# This operation is not allowed. Please contact Razorpay support for details. getting in transfers API (Live Mode)

Tags: php, wordpress, deployment, payment-gateway, razorpay

i getting this error "This operation is not allowed. Please contact Razorpay support for details." in razorpay  https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/tr_id/transfers API

i want to  split payments with vendors and platform owner.

i use this Endpoint
`https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/<tr_id>/transfers`

Request

```
{
  "transfers": [
    {
      "account": "acc_...",
      "amount": 1620,
      "currency": "INR",
      "notes": {
        "order_id": "3376",
        "transaction_id": "pay_....."
      },
      "linked_account_notes": [
        "order_id",
        "transaction_id"
      ],
      "on_hold": true,
      "on_hold_until": 1711516716
    }
  ]
}
```

response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
    "description": "This operation is not allowed. Please contact Razorpay support for details.",
    "source": "NA",
    "step": "NA",
    "reason": "NA",
    "metadata": {
      
    }
  }
}
```

```
    global $razorpay_secret;
    $api_url = "https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/$transaction_id/transfers";

    $data = array(
        'transfers' => $payments
    );
    $post_data = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $api_url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($razorpay_key_id . ':' . $razorpay_secret),
            "Content-Type: application/json"
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    $res = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: Provide some code, where the request is initiated

Comment: As per the documentation (https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/route/transfers/fetch-transfers-payment), I can see this is not a POST, it is GET, so modify this to :
`$api_url = "https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/$payment_id/transfers";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $api_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true, // Use GET method
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$razorpay_key_id:$razorpay_secret", // Set basic authentication credentials
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);`

Comment: you are right but this api is used to Fetch a Transfer With ID,
but i want to create transfers 

docs- https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/route/transfers/create-transfers-payments

Comment: I see, so, have you done all the steps https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/route/linked-account/

Comment: i have done all the steps and its work fine in testing mode but not in live mode